# Save title of button to django feild

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a button in my HTML that has a title attribute that changes depending on if I press a checkbox inside the button. The title is a list of all the elements inside the button that are checked.

(NOTICE THE TITLE ATTRIBUTE OF THE BUTTON TAG RELATES TO THE ITEMS THAT ARE CHECKED)

**I was wondering if there is a way to grab that dynamic title and store it in a Django model field like a listfield or something that accepts a list?**

[image]

[image]

I am using a piece of software called Bootstrap Multiselect (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) It calls for using a form (select/option) method rather than input

So far my HTML code is the following:

```
<select id="CMBootstrapMulti" multiple="multiple">
{%for obj in objects %}
    {% for element in obj.display_application %}
        <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{element}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
{%endfor %}
</select>
```

In the docs for this piece of software, it mentions something about passing a name into the select tags in order to do server side processing. Could this name attribute help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `button` and a `title` attr, I would use a form `input` element with a `type=hidden`. Reason being that it will post that data back to the server function that corresponds to that URL. Allowing you to save that data into a field of your choice.

As far as saving a `list of strings` in a `model field`, I would most likely just use a [`charfield`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) with a long `max_length`. Then create a method on that model that splits by some chosen delimiter. In your case you already have a comma as your delimiter, so your model might look something like the following.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    my_list_of_stuff = models.CharField(max_length=9999)

    def my_list_of_stuff_split(self):
        # this will return a list eg. `["foo, "bar", "pop" ...]`
        return self.my_list_of_stuff.split(",")
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Do you have any more insight on this situation?